# Can I treat all domain names as being IDNs without any ill effects?

Tags: internationalization, domain-name, idn, punycode

From testing, it seems like trying to convert both IDNs and regular domain names 'just works' - eg, if the input doesn't need to be changed punycode will just return the input.

```
punycode.toASCII('lancôme.com');
```

returns:

```
'xn--lancme-lxa.com'
```

And

```
punycode.toASCII('apple.com');
```

returns:

```
'apple.com'
```

This looks great, but is it specified anywhere? **Can I safely convert everything to punycode?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. If you look at how the procedure for converting unicode strings to ascii punycode, the process only alters any non-ascii character. Since regular domains cannot contain non-ascii characters, if your conversor is correctly implemented, it will never transform any pure-ascii string.

You can read more about how unicode is converted to punycode here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode

Punycode is specified in RFC 3492: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3492.txt, and it clearly says:

> "Basic code point segregation" is a very simple and
>      efficient encoding for basic code points occurring in the extended
>      string: they are simply copied all at once.

Therefore, if your extended string is made of basic code points, it will just be copied without change.

Comment: @mikemaccana the best reference is always the specification :)